# django returning 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, authentication, django-forms

I am developing a feature, when a user registers it automatically logs the user in
but i get `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'` error.

but when i use the same code to login the user it works fine.

my `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(error_messages=(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"fname entry", "placeholder":"First Name"}), required=True)
    lname = forms.CharField(error_messages=(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"lname entry", "placeholder":"Last Name"}), required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(error_messages=(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"phone entry", "placeholder":"Phone Number"}), required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"password entry", "placeholder":"Password", "autocomplete":"off"}), required=True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"password entry", "placeholder":"Confirm Password", "autocomplete":"off"}), required=True)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fname = self.cleaned_data.get("fname")
        lname = self.cleaned_data.get("lname")
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if phone and password and fname and lname and password2:
        
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(phone=PhoneNumber.objects.get(number=phone))
            if user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("user exists login instead")

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        if password!=password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("passwords didn't match")

        else:
            if len(password)<8:
                raise forms.ValidationError("short password! password should be longer than 8")
```

in my forms i have a registration form which does not inherit from django's user creation form.

my `views.py`:

```
def registerView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                       
           fname = form.cleaned_data.get("fname")
           lname = form.cleaned_data.get("lname")
           username = generate_username(fname, lname)
           phone = form.cleaned_data.get("phone")

           u = User.objects.create_user(email="", first_name=fname, last_name=lname, username=username, is_active=False)
           u.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
           u.save()
           p = PhoneNumber(user=u, number=phone)
           p.save()

           phone = PhoneNumber.objects.get(number=phone)
           u = User.objects.get(phone=phone)
           userLogin = authenticate(username=username, password=u.password)

        login(request, userLogin)
        return redirect('home')

  else:
    form = RegisterForm()

  return render(request, 'main/register.html', {'form':form})
```

my `loginView`:

```
def loginView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = LoginForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          phone = PhoneNumber.objects.get(number=form.cleaned_data.get('phone'))
          u = User.objects.get(phone=phone)
          user = authenticate(username=u.username, password=form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
          login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
          print('success')
          return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'main/login.html', {'form':form})
```

i have imported everything i need. the same code works with the `loginView` function but it doesn't work on `registerView`

What should i do to fix this?

Comment: You have indentation error in your views.py can you fix it by editing the question?
in the line:
if form.is_valid():

Comment: Apart from the indentation error, the error you get shows that the user is not created because `AnonymousUser` is an empty default user.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your view:

```
userLogin = authenticate(username=username, password=u.password)
```

The point to be noted here is that `u` is an instance of the user model and `u.password` will give the hashed password while `authenticate` expects it to be a raw password and hence returns `None`. In fact you don't even need to use `authenticate` while registering as you already have the user instance:

```
def registerView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fname = form.cleaned_data.get("fname")
            lname = form.cleaned_data.get("lname")
            username = generate_username(fname, lname)
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get("phone")
            
            # removed `is_active=False` as per comment by @Nahu Gere
            user = User.objects.create_user(email="", first_name=fname, last_name=lname, username=username) # better variable name
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
            user.save()
            phone = PhoneNumber(user=user, number=phone)
            phone.save()
            login(request, user) # Directly use saved user instance
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'main/register.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it it no longer returned that error but it doesn't login the user

Comment: Never mind i fixed it by removing `is_active=False` in the line that creates the user. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because In my register view, I had this code:

```
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

then I had so the user got logged in automatically after registering an account.

```
user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
login(request, user)
```

---

**I solved it by commenting out the auto login**

```
# user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
# login(request, user)
```